# React Native Date object different behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datetime

Logging out a new Date object shows different result in hours than logging it out parsed to string.
I know React Native uses different JS engine than Chrome, so I am using Flipper, which connects directly to the metro bundle, and the app is not in debug mode. My code is simple:

```
componentDidMount() {
     console.log(new Date());
     console.log(new Date().toString())
     console.log('Hours :' + (new Date()).getHours());
 }
```

I get the following result:

> 2020-04-23T10:51:15.683Z
>
> Thu Apr 23 2020 12:51:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)
>
> Hours :12

How is the our different? Is it something related to JS itself that I am not aware of, or is it RN specific?

Comment: The behaviour of consoles is not standardised so is implementation dependent. When passed to *log*, the Date is stringified. Often, *toString*, which returns a "local" string, is used but some consoles use *toISOString*, which returns a UTC string. That is the difference between the two timestamps: the first is UTC (+0 offset) the second is CEST (+2 offset). Both represent the same instant in time. *getHours* returns the local hour, *getUTCHours* returns the UTC hour.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date("2020-04-23T10:51:15.683Z").getHours()
> 12
```

```
new Date("2020-04-23T10:51:15.683Z")
Thu Apr 23 2020 12:51:15 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

The date is fine, it doesn't show `10` hours because it's GMT +2